# Is is safe not to backup data on other partitions when performing a clean install?

Tags: installation, backup

I have **Ubuntu 12.04** peacefuly coexisting with **Windows7** using *dualboot*.

I would like to make a fresh installation of **Ubuntu 13.04**, which would replace **Ubuntu 12.04**.

I have already backed up my files from the *Ubuntu* partition, but I would like to **avoid** having to backup the *Windows* data. Is it safe? According to my simplistic views of how the partition system works, as long as the disk drivers are working fine, there is very little that can go wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How important is the data?

If your data is important to you, then you should have a back up, period.

Although a fresh install almost always goes smoothly, there is always the chance you could mis type or make a mistake, or the install could fail.

The hard drive could fail independent of the install.

You could have a power failure.

etc

Bottom line, IMO you should have a working backup if you value your data, fresh install or not.